# Committing changes from Heroku to Github / BitBucket

Tags: heroku, strapi, heroku-cli

I'm using [Strapi](https://strapi.io/) my content management system, hosted on Heroku. However, I'd like to be able to edit content directly on the Heroku server, and pull those changes to my local environment at a later date, when more extensive CMS development is required.

It is well documented how to deploy changes from local -> Heroku, but not the other way around.
Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Has my answer below helped in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you asking but I'm going to try...

Lets first understand the two main moving parts in Strapi.

1. The **content-type-builder** (use the content-type builder to create a content type eg. books)

- 1.1) You should always create your content-types using the content-type-builder in your
  local environment and then push it to your host(Heroku)
  This is also recommended by Strapi and to enforce it they have disabled the content-
  type-builder plugin when NODE_ENV is set to production.

2. The **content-type-data** (use the above created books-content-type to create a book)

- 2.1) As of writing this Strapi v3.1.4 Strapi cannot move your content-type-data between environments for you. ie. If you create a books content-type and you use it to create a book in your localhost environment then that book will only exist in your local environment.

If you do need/want to move your content-type-data between environments you need to develop a migration mechanism that will seed the data from one database to the next.

as a rough example:
In your ./config/functions/bootstrap.js file you can create a module that gets content-type-data from your heroku instance via the public api and seeds that into your local database.
For this to work you need to set the content-types' permission for read access in the heroku app.

example bootstrap.js

```
const productionSeed= require('./seeds');
module.exports = async () => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
    await productionSeed.seedData();
    }
};
```

example seed.js

```
module.exports.seedData= async () => {
    try {
        //Sudo code:
        var books = GET http://{heroku-app-name}/books
    
        foreach(book in books){
            await strapi.services.books.create({
            name: book.name;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

This is the long way of doing it when the use case is simple.
A Production database should be migrated using a migration script which you can call and use in the same way.

If you want to move the actual content-type then you will have to clone your heroku git repository, you can do so using `heroku git:clone -a {app name}`

**N.B** A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort.

you can find out more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was hoping that heroku would allow for a `heroku git:commit -am "commit message"` type command that would allow the platform to commit changes back to the repository. Certainly, there is a lot of information there to get started. Thank you

Comment: If you feel my answer did clear things up for you or helped in anyway, please could vote on it and mark it as the correct answer, thank you

Comment: Also I think you Aubrey mid understanding that command. Heroku’s version control repository is not the same as your github version control Repository...